# PHP and Mysql : explode 2 strings into a three different fields on a table

Tags: php, mysql, nested

Hi there i've 2 fields in a mysql database with similar content:

**Field 1**: `a>b>c` 
**Field 2**: `1>2>3`

I wish to put them in different rows, exploded.

Example:

```
-----------------
|Field 1|Field 2|      
|----------------
|a      |1      |
|b      |2      |
|c      |3      |
```

Here a snippet for the code that should make the work:

```
$result = mysql_query($insert_cat);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    //assegno variabili per l'array associativo
    $idcat = $row["id_categorie"];
    $descat = $row["categoria"];

    //inizio a ciclare all'interno degli array per ricavare le categorie
    $ar_id=explode('>',$idcat);
    $ar_des=explode('>',$descat);

    foreach($ar_id as $value_id)
    {

        foreach($ar_des as $value_des)
        {

        }

        echo $value_id.'|'.$value_des."\n";
    }
}
```

The problem is: how can I (for testing) echoing what should be inserted in the table?
I've tried but with no luck.

Comment: What happens, if you print_r($row); Is there anything in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the `array_combine` function - see the [php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) on the subject.

This will merge two arrays, with the first as they keys for the second.  As a result you can replace your `foreach` loops with something like this

```
$fullArray = array_combine($ar_id, $ar_des);
foreach($fullArray as $key_id => $val_des)
{
    echo $key_id . " | " . $val_des;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using mysql_* functions are highly not recommended and also deprecated for long time, the code is vulnerable to sql injection and my suggestion is to use PHP API for MySql: mysqli or PDO.

[See red box in this link for more info](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

[Help for choosing API](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)